# 特定ファイルの中身を動的に変更してGatlingで負荷テストをしたい

Tags: scala, gatling

Gatlingを使って負荷テストを行っています。

負荷テストの対象となっている画面のログインする際のユーザIDを動的に変更したいのですが、編集したシナリオを起動するとエラーを吐いてしまいGatlingが起動できない状態です。

[負荷テストツールGatling Tips(実践的なScalaスクリプト)](https://web.plus-idea.net/2018/02/gatling-tips-scala-script/)

上記サイトの「複数のログイン・ユーザのIDとパスワードをcsvファイルに定義し、パラレルにログインするシナリオを実行する」という部分を参考にしながら、自動生成されたシナリオを変更しています。

●シナリオ（scala)　（自動生成されたシナリオを多少内容を変更しております。）

```scala
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

import io.gatling.core.feeder.BatchableFeederBuilder

class aaa extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("http://example.com")  //URLは伏せさせていただきます。
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .contentTypeHeader("text/xml; charset=utf-8")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)")

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "Proxy-Connection" -> "Keep-Alive",
        "SOAPAction" -> "http://example.com")  //URLは伏せさせていただきます。


        val login_feeder = csv("LoginUser.csv").circular

    val scn = scenario("aaa")
            .feed(login_feeder)
            .exec(http("request_0")
            .post("/public/")  //負荷テストの対象となる画面IDが入ります
            .headers(headers_0)
            // 以下 0000_request.dat の中に "StrUserId" があります。
            .body(RawFileBody("C:/tool/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.5.0-bundle/user-files/resources/aaa/0000_request.dat")) 
            .formParam("StrUserId", "%{UserId}"))



    setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(login_feeder.records.length) during(180 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

●出力されるエラー

> [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - C:/tool/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.5.0-bundle/user-files/simulations/aaa.scala:35:42: value records is not a member of
> io.gatling.core.feeder.BatchableFeederBuilder[String]#F
> setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(login_feeder.records.length) during(180
> seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)

※エラーの場所を示す「＾」はsetUpの()内のrecordsの「r」の下についております。

●LoginUser.csv　の中身

```
UserId
0000010000
0000020000
0000030000
0000040000
0000050000
```

どなたか対処方法をご教授いただけませんでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

---

**※追記**
ご教授いただいた方法を試してみたところ、エラーは吐かなくなりGatlingを起動するに成功しました。

ですが、本題であったユーザIDは動的に変更していませんでした。
`0000_request.dat`内の`StrUserId`には`0000010000`が入っており、5ユーザ分`0000010000`のユーザIDでログインしておりました。

再度の質問になりますが、ユーザIDを動的に変更しながら負荷テストを実施する方法についてご存知の方がおられましたらご教授いただきたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 修正後のコードは `.feed(login_feeder.circular)` になっていて UserIdが変わらない、という事でしょうか？ `.circular` はfeedのデータを循環して使用してくれます。少なくとも私の環境では変わっているようでした(5回目のSessionは `UserId -> 0000050000` になっています)

Comment: また、`"%{UserId}"` ではなく `${UserId}` に修正する必要もありそうですが、結局送信されるbodyのcontentが `.body(RawFileBody())` の内容になっていることが原因な気もしました。

Comment: 回答を更新してみました。「動的に実施」する箇所に関しての回答にはなっていそうな気がします。どのような形式のFormデータを期待しているのかわかりませんでしたので、調べても期待しているようなFormデータが送信できない、という事であれば別途質問を立てて頂ければと思います。

Comment: ご教授していただきありがとうございます。
datファイルを編集して確認したところ、そもそもStrUserIdではなく、szSessionIDを変更しないとログイン時のユーザIDは変わっていないようでした。

更新前のコードで、formParamの”StrUserId”を”szSessionID"と変更して実施してみましたが、ログイン時のユーザIDは変わっていませんでした。

今から更新後のコードを試してみようと思います。それでも動的に実施ができてなかった場合はおっしゃられているように別途質問を立てさせて頂きます。
再度のご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: datのファイルの中身はCSV(feeder)の値によって変わるものではないので、質問を変えたほうが良い気がしてきましたね(今しがた理解しました)。その場合はやはりサーバー側が期待しているformの形式が質問文に書かれていないと、動的にどういうformデータを送信すべきなのか分からないのでダメですが。

Comment: もしかしたらですが、LoginUser.csvに列をいくつか追加して、ユーザー毎に送信すべきデータ(datファイルに書かれているもの)をすべてCSVに書いておき、全部 `.formParam()` でPOSTすれば解決する問題なのかもしれませんね(完全に勘ですが)

Comment: 様々な案を考えてくださりありがとうございます。現在、status.find.in(200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,304), found 415というGatingのエラーが出ていて、このエラーを解決するために調査を行っていたのですが、content-Typeにdatを扱うものがなさそうでしたので、このエラーの解決は厳しそうです。

Comment: datファイルの中身はCSV(feeder)の値で変えることができないのですね。そういうことでしたら、別の方法を考えた方が良いのかもしれないと思いました。
わざわざ考えてくださったのにすみません。

Comment: `ELFile` というテンプレート形式のファイルであれば、ファイル内に書かれた `${}` の部分がCSV(feeder)の値に置換されてリクエストされます。回答を更新しましたので、もしよろしければお試しください。

Comment: 新たに更新頂いてた、ElFileBodyを用いる方法でGatlingを起動してみたところ、ユーザIDを動的に変更しながら負荷テストを実施することに成功いたしました！
非常に助かりました。対応していただきありがとうございました。
また他の不明点が発生した際に質問を立てさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参照されている記事が古いためコンパイルエラーが出ているものと思います。

お使いの環境やバージョンは分かりませんが、少なくとも Gatling 3.5.1 では `readRecords: Seq[Record[Any]]` によりCSVのデータにアクセスする必要があるかと思います。

---

`SOAPAction` から察するに、datファイルの中身はxmlだったりしますでしょうか？

なにかしらのテンプレートファイル(xml, dat, etc.)の中身をCSV(feeder)の値に置換してリクエストを行う場合、`ElFileBody()`が利用できます。

**LoginUser.csv**

```
UserId
0000010000
0000020000
0000030000
0000040000
0000050000
```

**LoginUser.xml**

ファイル内でCSV(feeder)の値で置換したい箇所を `${}` で記述しておきます。

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<szSessionID>${UserId}</szSessionID>
```

**変更後のScalaコード**

```scala
  val login_feeder = csv("LoginUser.csv")

  val scn = scenario("aaa")
    .feed(login_feeder.circular)
    .exec(
      http("request_0")
        .post("/public/")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .body(ElFileBody("LoginUser.xml"))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(login_feeder.readRecords.length) during(180 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

**実行時の結果**

```
=========================
Session:
Session(aaa,5,HashMap(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> http://example.com, gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts -> io.gatling.http.util.SslContexts@7f7ff3d1, gatling.http.referer -> http://example.com/public/, UserId -> 0000050000, gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShufflingNameResolver@3a7d725a, gatling.http.cache.contentCache -> io.gatling.core.util.cache.Cache@73f6a724),KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$458/1157205972@5711bae9,io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop@413c5e1b)
=========================
HTTP request:
POST http://example.com/public/
headers:
        user-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)
        Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
        SOAPAction: http://example.com
        accept: */*
        host: example.com
        content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
        content-length: 80
body:StringChunksRequestBody{contentType='text/xml; charset=utf-8', charset=UTF-8, content=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<szSessionID>0000050000</szSessionID>
}
=========================
```

5回目のリクエストではテンプレートファイル(xml)の `${UserId}` が CSV ファイル5行目の `0000050000` に置換されてリクエストされていること分かります。

```
content=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<szSessionID>0000050000</szSessionID>
```

Comment: 返信が遅くなりました。ご回答ありがとうございます。

ご教授いただいた方法で試してみます。

ちなみに、
Gatlingのバージョンは　3.5.0
環境は　Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
です。

Comment: 新たに更新頂いてた、ElFileBodyを用いる方法でGatlingを起動してみたところ、ユーザIDを動的に変更しながら負荷テストを実施することに成功いたしました！ 非常に助かりました。対応していただきありがとうございました。 また他の不明点が発生した際に質問を立てさせていただきます。